# Stop multer from uploading when field is empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I'm trying to make a post request for users to update multiple parts of their profile at once, but if they only want to update their bio and not their profile picture for example, how can I stop multer from trying to upload if the field is left blank?

post request:

```
app.post('/updateprofile/:user_id',  upload.single("profilePic"), function(req, res){
  let newPic = req.file.filename
  let bio = req.body.bio
  ...
})
```

multer storage options:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './public/uploads')
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname)
  }
})
```

When I leave it empty the error I get is

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined
```

Comment: Check if file and filename exists: ```let newPic = (req.file !== undefined && req.file.filename !== undefined) ? req.file.filename : undefined;```. Note that the code can be reduced as ```let newPic = req?.file?.filename``` using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). Of course, later you **must** check if ```newPic``` is different from ```undefined``` (```newPic !== undefined```). If true, upload. If false, do nothing.

Comment: PS: I think it's better if you set ```newPic``` and ```bio``` as ```const``` variables.

Comment: I would separate that into 2 endpoints, 1 to upload image and another one to update the other data.

Answer (score 0):

just check if any file was added with `if (!req.file) { //Dont do anything since there is no file } else { //do something  const fileName = req.file.filename; }`